# Randomly setting up parameter values using reflection

Tags: c#, types, reflection, sizeof

I have a "Param" object (part of a "module" object) with the "Value" property that can be of any type, such as int, int[], int[,], int[][], etc.

Now, I would like to write a test that randomly populate those parameter values, but I am having the problem that those Values can be of pretty much any type.
Also note that in this application there are many many many parameters, so the way of finding out the Type of each "Value" and how to set it has to be generic. I would think the only approach is to use reflection, but I got stuck pretty quickly as I cannot even find out the size of "Value", which will vary depending on "Value" being either a scalar or an array.
Is there a way I could get the size of "Value" as we would normally get from ".Count()" or ".length" using reflection (or other approach)?

So far I am only able to get the type of a given "Value", but that does not give me the size:

```
var valueType = module.GetPropValue($"{Param.Name}.Value").GetType();
```

Any suggestion would be very welcome.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Dai, because I am writing a test that needs to randomly populate those "Values", but I have no way of knowing how many random values I need to generate.

Comment: Why not just type them as `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`? That has a `.Count` property that most collections implement - you can also check for `ICollection<T>` for older collection types too.

Comment: @Dai, how would that work? How would you set <T>. That can be anything.

Comment: Right, so just make _that_ method generic too, or use `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` for runtime generics.

Comment: @Dai would you have an example on how to set random values to any parameter types? Maybe it should be the title of my thread.

Comment: Please edit your question-post to include _far more_ context and examples of how you intend to call it, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Dai, I just added some more context/clarifications

Comment: ...what you've written really doesn't help at all.

Comment: A "random" array necessarily also has a random length. For things like jagged and multidimensional arrays, this gives you a *lot* of possibilities as to what to make the random array look like, with most of those values uninteresting from a code coverage perspective. Consider also values of types like `class A { public A(string); }`, which require generating non-default constructor calls. All in all using static code analysis like Roslyn makes for an easier way to write this kind of fuzz testing than reflection does.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen Mostert, I will check it out. Do you have an example I could use as a basis for this?

Comment: No, it was just a general observation. Without knowing what the module does and why you have to feed it random values it's hard to say what the best approach is, just that going completely random ("dumb" fuzzing) quickly shows diminishing returns, especially if you have to theoretically consider every possible type.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, the Values of each Parameter, contained in each module is sent to a DSP Ram. I want to randomly populate that memory and then read it back using a different approach to make sure the RAM gets R/W properly, nothing really relevant to my question though :-)
But considering what you are saying, I understand that hardcoding a test for each Value type is probably the easiest, although not generic.

Comment: DSPs are typically very limited in what kinds of types they support, if they even have higher-order types (as opposed to integers, floating-point values and one-dimensional  arrays of those). If all you need to do is test RAM it seems quite probable you don't even need to support any kind of types beyond `byte[]` -- how the bytes are interpreted on a higher level is irrelevant. You may need to find a lower-level API to feed it raw bytes, though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, that would be nice indeed, but I am trying to test the higher level API here. ie. The one that converts those Values into raw numbers and writes them to the DSP. I want to make sure that the correct things get there and that the correct floating point to fixed point conversions are applied (or vice versa).

Comment: Then it seems very probable you still don't actually want *random* values or *any* type, since the most interesting values will be the extremes and patterns (empty, 0, infinity, NaN, 32768, `0b0101010101010101`, and for arrays 0, 1, 2, 3 elements and maximum length the API supports, that sort of thing). If you do go random, at least make sure the tests are deterministic (so seed the RNG) and even then you can probably just support a fixed number of interesting types, instead of literally "anything".